# Namespace color scheme

Tags: colorscheme

Hi I'm a new vim user (1 week), I just switched my color scheme to monokai, however a point let me dissatisfied, c++ namespaces are not highlighted.
I tried :

```
hi namespace guifg=[my color]
```

and

```
hi Namespace guifg=[my color]
```

without any results.

Does anyone know a way around ?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! You’ll need to know the correct highlighting group to override. There are a plethora of plugins to help with this (my own github.com/benknoble/vim-synstax being one of them).

Comment: Thanks !!! I'm gonna take a look ;)

Comment: Great that was exactly what I was looking for !!!

Comment: Np! Please self-answer if you were able to solve your problem to help future users :)

Comment: I did, but a need to wait two days to validate.

Comment: Great! Glad you were able to find it

Answer (score 3):

The identifier was `cppSTLnamespace`.
Thanks to @D.Ben Knoble for his [plugin](https://github.com/benknoble/vim-synstax)!

The full command is

```
hi cppSTLbamespace guifg=...
```